# No upvoted answers custom tags

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

I would like to list questions with certain tags, and no upvoted answers. This

[stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags)

is close but it does not let you choose the tags. This

[stackexchange.com/filters/78496/stack-overflow?sort=noanswers](https://stackexchange.com/filters/78496/stack-overflow?sort=noanswers)

is close but it is "no answers", not "no upvoted answers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access this at [stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/yourtag+your2ndtag+your3rdtag](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/yourtag+your2ndtag+your3rdtag) but I'm not sure how you get there through the interface.

Comment: does this give no UPVOTED anssers, or just no answers?

Comment: @Ian No upvoted answer, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/regex+sql+mysql+sql-server+php+javascript+html)